# UIImageView layer order

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, layer

I am having trouble understanding how layering is performed within Xcode. I have a .xib with a view, that view has 6 `UIImageView` 's which each contain a different image. I have created `IBOutlets` for each of these so I can change the image at runtime.

I now want to change the order the UIImageViews are drawn at runtime, so imageA at the back is now drawn on top of everything else. How can I change the layer order? I originally tried removing all the subviews and using `[self.view insertSubview: atIndex: ]` to see if I could change the draw order that way but my code crashes.

Can anyone tell me the correct method for doing this please?

Thanks in advanced,
Elliott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you are looking for these UIView methods:

1:
exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
Exchanges the subviews at the specified indices.

```
- (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2
```

2:
bringSubviewToFront:
Moves the specified subview so that it appears on top of its siblings.

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

3:
sendSubviewToBack:
Moves the specified subview so that it appears behind its siblings.

```
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view
```

with these methods you can exchange the subviews order to get one UIView appear over one other in their superview... if that's what you were asking....

Comment: Perfect thank you! I will have a look into these methods tomorrow as they look like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Nice. I never looked for the bring/send pair. Figured I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

A crash may be because when you remove the image from its parent, its retain count goes to zero and is deallocated.

If you just want to swap two views, see `- (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2` on `UIView`. If you want to do a more complicated exchange, you can remove and readd, just make sure you retain the view you remove (ARC notwithstanding).

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling you are right and that's causing a crash, I will try with the exchange method as it should do what I need.